# I wrote a code for my window and I have some Entry boxes, but the thing that I want is when all boxes aren't fill, the user couldn't go to next step

Tags: python

actually I want a way to help me detect empty boxes and after that I can consider an alert for my user to say: 'fill all boxes' before go to next step. If you know my answer please help me.

for example my entry box is: 'Name'

Comment: Can you upload code snippet or screenshot for better understanding ?

Comment: Are you using tkinter

Comment: @UserOne yes I am

Answer (score 0):

You can get what's inside Entry widget using `get` method like:

```
name = tkinter.Entry(root)
name_string = name.get()
```

Then you would check if the string is empty or not. You would then do this for all or your entry boxes.

Comment: How should I understand if a box is empty? with which code?